# How to get specific data from JSON URL and get it to my filter search using Typeahead.js?

Tags: javascript, json, url, filter, typeahead

I'm trying to accomplish filter search box using typeahead.js. I would prefer executing search query in source-url. But how is it possible to achieve that when I have multiple columns behind the url, like this:

```
{
    "userId": 1,
    "id": 1,
    "title": "delectus aut autem",
    "completed": false
  },
  {
    "userId": 1,
    "id": 2,
    "title": "quis ut nam facilis et officia qui",
    "completed": false
  },
  {
    "userId": 1,
    "id": 3,
    "title": "fugiat veniam minus",
    "completed": false
  },
```

Right now my search is giving "Undefined". I'd like to filter all titles from whole JSON list. (https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos)

And here's typeahead.js attempt for filtering search results. Right now getting undefined values under the search box:

```
options.typeahead = {
  datasets: {
     type: 'remote',
     source: 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos',
     limit: 25
    }
  };
```

Comment: Is it mandatory to use Typeahead ? you can do it easily without it

Comment: Well, not mandatory really. You could always suggest me another approach as well. Should I leave URL query search and try something else?

Comment: You can try `const titles = new Set(data.map(item=>item.title))`. If you need the 25 first `titles = [...titles].slice(0,25)`. I use set here to be sure to have no duplicate.